# Why can't we call the method of the class using the class's object outside a method?

Tags: java, oop

```
    public class Basics {  

        Basics b = new Basics(); 



        int instanceVariable = 0; 

        public void behavior() {      
          System.out.println("Print Something");
        }       

        b.behavior();   // Why this line, b.behavior doesn't work?

        public static void main(String[] args){
          Basics b = new Basics();   /* Why are we allowed to create an 
                                          * object of same name again within
                                          * the same class */
          b.behavior(); // This line works
        }


}
```

In the above class, I am able to create object . But I can't call `b.behavior` outside any class, but I am able to do that within a method. Why is that so? What is the difference?

```
public class Basics1 extends Basics{

     Basics b = new Basics();
     Basics1 b1 = new Basics1();

     b = b1.instanceVariable;  // I don't see error in this line, but previous line shows //error.
     b1.instanceVariable // This line doesn't work


}
```

Why is `b1.instanceVariable` not working, `instanceVariable` is the base class instance variable.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to execute/retrieve something outside of a method/block/assignment. What do you expect the stray `b.behavior()` and `b1.instanceVariable` to do?

Comment: _Read the error message_.  What part don't you understand?

Comment: I expect b.behavior() to print the code within the method. I don't expect anything. I would like to know why Java doesn't allow any one to write like that. What's the reason behind constructing a language like this?

Comment: @user3659479: What would you expect that to do? When would it run?

Comment: But what is `b` in that scope?

Comment: @SLaks : The error message says "Syntax error on token "behavior", Identifier expected after this token". What does this mean?

Comment: It means you made a syntax behavior. I believe that it thinks you're trying to define a variable/field.

Comment: @user3659479: Sorry; I thought you were asking about accessibility.  Next time, _tell us the error message_; don't make us guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that a class is a "type definition", not a code block or sequence of statements.

You cannot just write arbitrary statements in a type definition.

Even so, `"b1.instanceVariable"` is not a statement. `"b1.instanceVariable"` doesn't mean anything in statement context.

Comment: Could you explain what is mean by type definition? I couldn't find an answer in Google.

Comment: A type definition is a general computer science term, meaning a specification or definition of a variable. In Java, all variables will be of some type. The class is the way you tell Java the specification (or blueprint) to use to create instances of the class (object). Type definitions are rules, not actions.

Comment: A cake recipe is the type definition. Baking a cake gets you an "object" of that type. In Java, you have to bake the cake with "new".

Answer (score 3):

A class defines variables and methods. *b.behavior();* is a statement that cannot be on its own like that.

Comment: `Object x = b.behaviour();` would work (defines and assigns a field). But the method is void. (Just to answer the question about what the scope shoudl be).

Answer (score 2):

All code needs to be in methods, in field declarations (such as `Basics b = new Basics();` in your example) or in "initializer blocks" (which are run as part of constructors or during class initialization).

This is just a syntax rule.

In other languages, you can have this kind of "raw code", to achieve various effects. What do you want to achieve?

- run during compilation (like in Perl): Cannot be done in Java
- run during constructor: use an init block
- run during class loading: use a static init block
- run when the program starts: put it in static void main
- run during method invokation: put it in that method

Comment: This was a great answer. But I was allowed to chose only one accepted answer. But well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write code anywhere and expect it to execute is a form of procedural programming. In this form , you tend to loose context and soon the code becomes a spaghetti code --> methods getting called anywhere , anytime.

With OOP, you are trained to create objects with well defined methods which have a defined context. Just think, when would you like to get the  b.behavior(); being called : Before initializing a class, after initializing the class, after execution of main or when the object is destroyed?

Interestingly, Java has defined syntaxes for each of the states.. You can wrap  your code  in  { System.out.println("Hello World "); }  and it will execute when the class is instantiate...Also you can use static { System.out.println("Hello World "); } and this will execute when class is loaded.   But again, this is part of telling the JVM when to do it - an agreed upon syntax.. But without any marker around your code, when would you actually expect to run?